# SQL sum values day by day from datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I've got a table:

```
Date                    NETTO   VAT
2018-09-18 13:06:48.287 15.00   2.80
2018-07-21 17:32:28.620 8.55    1.60
2018-09-07 12:43:07.487 50.70   9.48
2018-09-07 19:32:06.530 57.20   10.70
2018-09-03 17:12:13.837 79.00   14.77
2018-09-08 14:54:25.367 110.45  20.65
2018-10-01 13:04:53.917 60.90   11.39
```

Date is `datetime` type 
like `2018-06-15 12:22:43.312`

I tried to convert `datetime` to `date` but I can't view sum of the NETTO and VAT

```
select 
  CONVERT(date, data_sp, 111) As Date, 
  SUM(w_csb) as NETTO , 
  SUM(w_vat) as VAT 
from 
  sales
Group by 
  data_sp
Order by 
  data_sp
```

I'd like to get the result like this:
sum day by day

```
2018-06-15  3335.75 236.68
2018-06-16  199.00  37.21
2018-06-17  1115.00 232.80
```

Comment: please stop messing up the question formatting and trying to use HTML - StackOverflow will not let you inject HTML. use the Markdown editing tools available in the editor window instead. I've fixed it for you this time. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. Since your edit, your desired output data no longer matches the input data, so it doesn't make as much sense. We get the idea though. I've posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either [fa06's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53882286/5947043) should work for you, or, if you convert your `datetime` to a `varchar` instead of a `date` you'll get a slightly neater output (without the zero-d time):

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(varchar(10), data_sp, 111) AS Date, 
  SUM(w_csb) AS NETTO, 
  SUM(w_vat) AS VAT 
FROM
  sales
GROUP BY 
  CONVERT(varchar(10), data_sp, 111) 
ORDER BY 
  CONVERT(varchar(10), data_sp, 111)
```

The important point is that the shortened date must be in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses as well as the `SELECT`, otherwise it only groups by the *original* date, which still includes times, and therefore the dates are still seen as unique values - and thus not group-able.

Based on your sample data above, my query will output:

```
Date        NETTO   VAT
2018/07/21  8.55    1.60
2018/09/03  79.00   14.77
2018/09/07  107.90  20.18
2018/09/08  110.45  20.65
2018/09/18  15.00   2.80
2018/10/01  60.90   11.39
```

Most of your dates only appear once anyway, but as you can see it has grouped `2018-09-07` correctly.

Working demo (of both mine and fa06's query): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ed0d4ca3ebd8e45e02be41aaf86c2ef4

Comment: . . Leaving the length off a `varchar` is just a bad, bad habit.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. Any particular reason, though?

Comment: . . The default length varies by context in SQL Server.  When the string is not big enough, then you have a very hard to find bug.

Comment: @GordonLinoff fair enough, thanks. See edited answer. Forgive my ignorance, but what controls the default length, precisely?

Answer (score 2):

You can try below using `cast(data_sp as date)` for date conversion and also add it in `group by` clause

```
select cast(data_sp as date) As Date, SUM(w_csb) as NETTO , SUM(w_vat) as VAT 
from sales 
Group by cast(data_sp as date) 
order by cast(data_sp as date)
```

Comment: still have resault :

Date NETTO VAT <p>
2018-06-15 199.00 37.21<p>
2018-06-15 35.75 6.68<p>
2018-06-16 199.00 37.21<p>
2018-06-17 15.00 2.80<p>
2018-06-17 19.95 3.73<p>

i want have a sum of a day by day

Comment: @ArturStolc . . . You should not be getting duplicates on each day with this code.  This is a much better answer than converting to a string.